# problem with XAMPP, access forbidden... looking for d:\xampp not c:\xampp

Tags: apache, xampp

I have been using xampp for a while now without any problem. All of a sudden I start xampp today and I am getting an "Error 403 Access Forbidden" when I try to go to my Localhost.

When I check the error logs for apache it says:

[Mon Mar 22 21:48:57 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: D:/xaamp

This is strange, it should first of all say "C:" and second of all say "Xampp" (not xaamp).  Where would I change this is my config files. Have no idea how this could have happened.

Comment: also, when i try to restart I get "can't find process #7032"

Answer (score 1):

I think this will be an Apache configuration problem. The configuration should be found in your `httpd.conf` at the location below:

```
\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf
```

Then find this property:

```
DocumentRoot
```

What does it say? It should say:

```
DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs"
```

Comment: Yes, here you should change DocumentRoot "YOUR_NEW_PATH" (line: 191) to a folder where you keep your webpages and 403 will gone :) add your path also to <Directory "YOUR_NEW_PATH"> in line 221 (xampp 1.8.1)